# Partial specialization non-top level cv qualifier ignored in function signature

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use something like the following test case:

```
/* Generic implementation */
template <typename T>
struct SpecWrapper {
   static void bar(T const* src) {
      printf("src[0] = %le\n", src[0]);
   }
}; 

/* Volatile partial-specialization */
template <typename T>
struct SpecWrapper<T volatile> {
   static void bar(T const* src) {
      printf("src[0] = %le\n", src[0]);
   }  
}; 

/* Instantiate */
void foo(double volatile const* src) {
   SpecWrapper<double volatile>::bar(src);
}
```

However this generates the following error with g++

```
test.cxx: In function ‘void foo(const volatile double*)’:
test.cxx:18:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘const volatile double*’ to ‘const double*’ [-fpermissive]
    LowLevel<double volatile>::bar(src);
                                      ^
test.cxx:12:16: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘static void LowLevel<volatile T>::bar(const T*) [with T = double]’ [-fpermissive]
    static void bar(T const* src) {
                ^
```

Can someone explain why this problem is arising? There are a few workarounds that spring to mind, but I would like to understand why it's a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
/* Volatile partial-specialization */
template <typename T>
struct SpecWrapper<T volatile> {
   static void bar(T volatile const* src) {
      printf("src[0] = %le\n", src[0]);
   }  
};
```

since `T` is just `double`.